# Why can't I get my div to fill up 100% of my window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to get a div to display with a 100% height of the window (640px), [image: but it only seems to render the height] of the `<h3>`. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm running the application in an emulator, does it have something to do with Cordova?

```
$(window).height(); // This is 640px.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Cordova scripts here -->

    <div style="height: 100%;" >

        <div id="d1" style="background-color: coral; height: 100%;">
            <h3>A div test.</h3>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add in CSS `#d1 { height: 100vh; }`

Comment: What is 100vh? And surely this just increases the size of the h3... I need to add other content in the div, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would usually set the body and html tag to be also 100% like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/81mc1qLb/1/):

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.full-width {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm marking this as the answer because the body and html height at 100% seems more standard.

Comment: Also you can remove the padding and margin of the body and then you will have full width and height for your elements.

Answer (score 4):

You should set it as 100% of your view-port:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but does it mean that all parent containers must be 100vh, and all child elements use 100%? Is this standard practice with hybrid apps?

Comment: it is standard practice, yes. About parents/children height, it works exactly like the percentage, it is just the percentage of the view-port

Comment: @Francescoes. _it works exactly like the percentage_ Not at all, if it then why to use `vh`?

Comment: @Tushar yes, it is right. The `vh` works always relative to the view-port, the percentage relative to the container. I express bad myself, I also wrote `it is just the percentage of the view-port`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `height` of body and html before div's `height`. You can see your request working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/piterio/945k796b/). With this css you can move on:

```
body, html{height: 100%;}
.height{height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**vh=viewport height**.please try reading this-> https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/